# How can I render 3d graphics in a directshow source filter

Tags: c++, 3d, directshow

I need to render a simple texture mapped model as the output of a directshow source filter.  The 3d rendering doesnt need to come from Direct3D, but that would be nice.  OpenGL or any other provider would be fine assuming I can fit it into the context of the DirectShow source filter.

visual studio 2008 c++

Comment: possible duplicate of [how-to-render-direct3d-in-a-directshow-source-filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985319/how-to-render-direct3d-in-a-directshow-source-filter) and [How to overlay 3d graphics on top of webcam feed live](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981497/how-to-overlay-3d-graphics-on-top-of-webcam-feed-live)

Comment: Kirill,  this post is similar but its not a duplicate.  The question is more general

Comment: I suppose the good idea would be to edit your another question which still has no accepted answer.

Comment: I think that would fundamentally change that question.  And for its worth I would still like an answer to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With direct3d I have found that you can call GetRenderTargetData from the d3d device to get you access to the raw image bytes that you can then copy into the source filters image buffer

Here is example code of how to get the d3d render

```
void CaptureRenderTarget(IDirect3DDevice9* pdev)
{
    IDirect3DSurface9* pTargetSurface=NULL;
    HRESULT hr=pdev->GetRenderTarget(0,&pTargetSurface);
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        D3DSURFACE_DESC desc;
        hr=pTargetSurface->GetDesc(&desc);
        if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            IDirect3DTexture9* pTempTexture=NULL;
            hr=pdev->CreateTexture(desc.Width,desc.Height,1,0,desc.Format,D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM,&pTempTexture,NULL);
            if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                IDirect3DSurface9* pTempSurface=NULL;
                hr=pTempTexture->GetSurfaceLevel(0,&pTempSurface);
                if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    hr=pdev->GetRenderTargetData(pTargetSurface,pTempSurface);
                    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        //D3DXSaveTextureToFile(L"Output.png",D3DXIFF_PNG,pTempTexture,NULL);
                        D3DLOCKED_RECT data;
                        hr=pTempTexture->LockRect(0, &data, NULL, 0);
                        if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
                        {
                            BYTE *d3dPixels = (BYTE*)data.pBits;                                            
                        }
                        pTempTexture->UnlockRect(0);
                    }
                    pTempSurface->Release();
                }
                pTempTexture->Release();
            }
        }
        pTargetSurface->Release();
    }
}
```